# How to implement aws.sdk.ts file in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, typescript

I have tried using aws-sdk.ts file in my mainmodule.ts file a below. But getting undefined error.

```
/// <reference path="aws.sdk.ts" />
import * as AWS from 'aws.sdk';
var typeScriptViewModel = function (first, last) {
    var self = this;
    AWS.Config({
        accessKeyId: 'ABC',
        secretAccessKey: 'ABCSECRET'
    });

    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; 

   // many more usage of AWS. but got stuck on the first implementation itself.
   //var bucket = new AWS.S3({
   //         params: {
   //             Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: path, Delimiter: '/'
   //         }
   //     });
}
```

It throws an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Config' of undefined".

Can anyone please guide me how to use s3 bucket using aws.sdk.ts?
I am new in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure about this being the problem but your reference should be:

```
/// <reference path="aws.sdk.d.ts" />
```

Instead of:

```
/// <reference path="aws.sdk.ts" />
```

Then you will be able to import:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws.sdk';
```

Make sure that you have installed both the type definitions:

```
$ typings install --global --save dt~aws-sdk
```

And the npm module:

```
$ npm install --save aws-sdk
```

## Update

You have [typings.json](https://github.com/remojansen/AwsDemo/blob/master/typings.json) outside of your `awsdemo` folder but you are also using `packages.config` (the Visual Studio way to manage `.d.ts` files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="aws-sdk.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="1.9.4" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="node.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="RequireJS" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="requirejs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

You can't use nuget and typings you need to use one of the two.

I would recommend you to follow the [official tutorial](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html). The tutorial explains how to install angular ignore that part and install aws-sdk instead. (You will probably need the es6-shim mentioned in the tutorial) as well.

Comment: https://github.com/Prashant-Kan/AwsDemo -  I have put a demo code here. Kindly check and let me know. 
I have tried /// <reference path="aws.sdk.ts" /> bye renaming the file and without renaming, but failed 
I tried to install the typings and aws-sdk but not getting success.

Answer (score 0):

There are many declaration files (.d.ts) available out there, but let's assume that you use the following declaration file:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/aws-sdk

You can do like this:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
var typeScriptViewModel = function (first, last) {
    const options = {
        accessKeyId: 'ABC',
        secretAccessKey: 'ABCSECRET',
        region: "us-east-1"
    };
    let s3 = new AWS.S3(options);

    // many more usage of AWS here
    // (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
    };
    s3.getBucketLocation(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your angular or ionic project run:

```
npm install aws-sdk --save
```

Before you can begin using these TypeScript definitions with your project, you need to make sure your project meets a few of these requirements:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```